# When a Piece-wise convex function is convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

Let $f : \Bbb R^n \to R \cup\{+ \infty\}$ be a piece-wise convex function, in the sense that $f$ admits the following representation (for simplicity consider only two pieces)

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 f_1 (x)& x \in P_1\\ 
 f_2 (x)& x \in P_2\\
+ \infty&   \rm{otherwise}  
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Where $f_i$ are smooth and convex on whole $\Bbb R^n$ , and $P_i$ are convex polyhedrals whose union is convex polyhedral as well.

I'm looking for conditions on $f_1 , f_2 $ which characterize the convexity of $f(x)$.

As an example of piecewise convex function which is not convex ; $f(x) = - |x|.$.In this example the monotonicity of the slopes of pieces fail. So I believe this characterization may pass through the monotonicity of gradients of pieces.

Even In particular cases when $f_i$ are linear or quadratic what can we say?

Comment: @user4412195  Just FYI, Monotonicity is also defined for set-valued map.   A function (not necessary smooth) is convex if and only in it's subdifferential in monotone operator. 

So in our case $\partial f$ is monotone operator, how can we rewrite this monotonicity property in terms of some property on $f_1 and f_2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need that the 'kink' between $f_1$ and $f_2$ has the correct sign.

Let us denote $\Gamma = P_1 \cap P_2$. This *should* be a $n-1$-dimensional set possessing a normal vector $\nu \in \mathbb R^n$ pointing from $P_1$ to $P_2$. Then, you have to check that
$$ \Bigl( \nabla f_2(x) - \nabla f_1(x) \Bigr)^\top \nu \ge 0$$
holds for all $x \in \Gamma$.

To see that this condition is necessary and sufficient, pick $p_1 \in P_1$ and $p_2 \in P_2$. Then, the segment $[p_1, p_2]$ intersects $\Gamma$ in one $x$. The above condition means that the derivative along this segment is increasing and therefore $f$ is convex along this segment. Finally, one can use that convexity is equivalent to convexity along all segments.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  why $n-1$ dimension ?, the intersection can be just one point, so the normal cone contains entire $\Bbb R^n$. or even $n$ dimension.
 
what do you mean pointing from $P-1$  to $P_2$ mathematically?

Also how does it work for more than two pieces ? I

Comment: If $P_1$, $P_2$ are full-dimensional $P_2$ and their union is convex, then the intersection cannot be only a point. In fact, it has to be $n-1$-dimensional. Pointing from $P_1$ to $P_2$ means that it is an outer normal vector of $P_1$. For more than two pieces, you have to do the same for all pair of adjacent pieces.

Comment: Clearly $P_1 , P_2$ are not necessarily full dimensional. But do you think this condition characterize convexity if restrict our self to $A:=\rm{Affin} (P_1  \cup  P_2)$ ?  In this case  $P_1$ and $P_2$ are full dimensional in $A$

Comment: Yes, you can restrict yourself to $A$ and then both sets are full-dimensional. In this case, my condition (together with the obvious $f_1 = f_2$ on the intersection) is sufficient and necessary for convexity.