# When a Piece-wise convex function is convex? ( Looking for a scond order-type condition )

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $f : \Bbb R^n \to R \cup\{+ \infty\}$ be a piece-wise convex function, in the sense that $f$ admits the following representation (for simplicity consider only two pieces)

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 f_1 (x)& x \in P_1\\ 
 f_2 (x)& x \in P_2\\
+ \infty&   \rm{otherwise}  
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Where $f_i$ are $C^2$ and convex on whole $\Bbb R^n$, (equivalently have PSD hessian everywhere) and $P_i$ are convex polyhedrals whose union is convex polyhedral as well.

I'm looking for conditions on $f_1 , f_2 $ in terms of their Hessian which characterize the convexity of $f(x)$.

"For a first order-type condition look at [When a Piece-wise convex function is convex?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2812060/219176) "

As an example of piecewise convex function which is not convex ; $f(x) = - |x|.$.In this example the monotonicity of the slopes of pieces fail. So I believe this characterization may pass through the monotonicity of gradients of pieces.

Even In particular cases when $f_i$ are linear or quadratic what can we say?

Comment: My condition from the other question already characterizes convexity. I feel that (in a certain sense) the convexity of $f$ is independent on the Hessians of $f_1$ and $f_2$. What matters is the possible (jump and) kink between $f_1$ and $f_2$ at $P_1 \cap P_2$ and this is determined by (the function values) and the gradients.

Comment: I also feel Hessian does not paly role , as in the case where $f_i$ are linear functions. I am just wondering  if there is a more realistic and verifiable condition for convexity. Your condition is correct but it actually requires checking the convexity of  all line passing through  **at** common points of any pair of $P_i , P_j$ . @gerw